# How to reference files in editor?

Tags: babylonjs

I added the textures to the editor with texture viewer, they show up under "Files" tab as `"MySkyboxTexture_px.png", "MySkyboxTexture_py.png"` etc, but how do I reference them in scripts? I.e. what is their path?
I tried multiple combinations, e.g. `./textures/MySkyboxTexture`, `./MySkyboxTexture` etc - nothing works.

```
skyboxMaterial.reflectionTexture = new BABYLON.CubeTexture(
    "MySkyboxTexture",  // <--- what do i put here?
    scene, ["_px.png", "_py.png", "_pz.png", "_nx.png", "_ny.png", "_nz.png"]
);
```

The debugger shows `file not found at ...BabylonJS Editor/resources/app.asar/MySkyboxTexture_px.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two ways to import an image:

- You just give a local path in your function, the path must start at the root of your app for example :

  ```
   -src/
   -index.js
   -assets/
       -file.png
   -style/
       -style.css
  ```

Then if you want to import file.png, you just have to give the url : `/assets/file.png`

- Another way to give an url is to first import your file as a blob and then create a blob url by doing the following (it can be a remote blob from a server or a local blob) :

```js
const url = URL.createObjectURL(myImportedBlob);
```

then use `url` as a param for your function.